# Animated GIF, should start animating on Button click

Tags: android, gif

I have a problem with making a gif animation playable on click. I found tutorials on how to insert a gif into an app, but all those gifs starts to animate immediately when you open the app, which I don't want.

I want my gif to start animating when I click on it.
I also want to make this gif as a button.. So when I click on this picture/gif it will start animating and it will also send an SMS to a specific number.

I will paste my code for button and my MainActivity code.
[image: button]
[image: source]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image - it makes it difficult to read and impossible to search. You should edit your post and include the relevant code as actual text.

Comment: Recently for a situation like this , playing GIF is kindof yesterday's news . 
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android this is super fun for playing complex animation . if you work solo , like if you don't have any designer with ok .  lottie has a websites with all of the coolest animation possible . check this out https://www.lottiefiles.com/

Comment: @BernoulliGate yeah I was thinking about that, but isnt there any command to hold the animation until you actually press on that gif?

Comment: @BernoulliGate okay thanks! I guess I have no other option than.. I was also thinking about adding a new page with button, and when you click on that button it will open a new page with that gif.. because I think adding 140frames will be a night mare..

Comment: okay that is actually very smart! :) I like it ! thanks for all your tips and your help in general!

Comment: I have an issue with my code.. App works on my old phone with android 5.0 but it doesnt work on my new phone with android 6.0 and other one with 7.0 version ... I basically copy / pasted code from one version to another, but 6.0 and 7.0, app is closing when I click on button with 0errors.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is separate your GIF into PNG **frames** with a sequential naming convention, if you have too many frames you can use for loop and a string builder to generate your **animation-list**, something like this:

[Split GIF into Frames - ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/split)

[Compile Java Online - compilejava.net](https://www.compilejava.net/)

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int x = 0;x<=140;x++) {
  sBuilder.append("<item");
  sBuilder.append("\n");
  sBuilder.append("  android:duration=\"500\"");
  sBuilder.append("\n");
  sBuilder.append("  android:drawable=\"@drawable/ic_heart_"+ x + "\"/>");
  sBuilder.append("\n");
}
System.out.print(sBuilder);
```

To create this **animation_list_filling.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:oneshot="true">

    <item
        android:duration="500"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_1"/>

    <item
        android:duration="500"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_2"/>

    <item
        android:duration="500"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_3"/>

    <item
        android:duration="500"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_4"/>

    <item
        android:duration="500"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_5"/> // etc...

</animation-list>
```

Setup the **ImageView** on your **Activity XML**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_animation_list_filling"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/animation_list_filling"
    />
```

Place this code on your **onClickListener** to start your GIF:

```
ImageView mImageViewFilling = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_animation_list_filling);
((AnimationDrawable) mImageViewFilling.getBackground()).start();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: very useful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I converted my comments to an answer, since this kind of a workaround can actually solve the problem.
Maybe some future users can take advantage of this "technique" as well.

---

1. > `but all those gifs starts to animate immediately when you open the app` You'd probably have better luck if you split your animated GIF into its frames. 
   >   And then animate those ones, instead.
2. > Animated GIFs are just a sequence of frames. They play immediately.
3. > `I guess I have no other option then...` There actually is another option: do something "in between". Show the first frame as a single image. When clicked, load the animated version.
   >   And this should be a viable solution: Easy and practical.